# How long should you wait to pour concrete on fresh concrete?

Tags: concrete, foundation

I'll soon be doing work in my basement that needs my plumber to break the foundation of my house

So they probably gonna break the concrete, do their work, then pour some more concrete to patch the hole.

Thing is, in that room, later in the renovations plan we would pour maybe an half inch of concrete in that whole room, make it get level to the floors of the basement.

But I know concrete usually expends slowly while curing. Would that cause a problem? How long should I wait for fresh concrete to cure before putting more concrete on top?

Comment: Usually you want to pour newer concrete as soon as possible so it bonds to the older, day or two.  1/2 inch concrete usually not thick enough to hold together, so I think you would need something else to raise it up.  Most other coverings think they would require the new concrete repair to cure for about 30 days.

Comment: If the plumber is going to “break the foundation” I hope you have an engineer and structural contractor ready to come in and do a structural repair. It’s very easy for a tradesperson, such as a plumber, to ruin the structure of a house.

Comment: @RibaldEddie the term might be a little strong. Basically we need to change out water return pipe and install a toilet in the basement so they need to break the foundation to do the changes. Seems to be a normal thing for a plumber to do. And usually if they accept the joke they have insurance if they fuck it up for you.

Comment: @crip659 might be another question but how thick of a layer of concrete would be minimal so it holds good? Or would there be another product that could lift us up half an inch for a bathroom? Our current plan is raise that half an inch with concrete then to some epoxy to finish.

Comment: To get the terms/names right, foundation is usually the walls(underground mainly), the floor(which I think you are talking about) is a slab or floor.  Concrete is a mix of cement, sand and stone(can be a bit bigger than 1/2 inch).  Would prefer the others who know better to answer about raising the floor a 1/2 inch.

Comment: Sorry, english is not my first language and i'm no professional. So I'm missing some technical terms. So concrete = with huge stones but the smooth stuff is what? Cement? I tought it was interchangable because in french both are called 'Ciment'. Just like the whole base of the house is called fondation, independent of if you are talking about the floor or the sides.